# Does $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x_n) = 0, X_n \overset{p}{\to} c$ implies $f_n(X_n) \overset{p}{\to} 0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I'm trying to solve the following,

> Does$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x_n)  = 0, \forall x_n, X_n \overset{p}{\to} c$$ implies $f_n(X_n) \overset{p}{\to} 0$? (where $f_n$ : continuous)

---

**What I tried**

By continuous mapping theorem, we have $f_m(X_n) \overset{p}{\to} f_m(c), \forall m$.

And since by letting $x_n=c$, I have $f_m(c) \to 0$. But can I derive from there the fact that $f_n(X_n) \overset{p}{\to} 0$?

Comment: Just to make sure, how are the conditional probability laws $\mathbb{P}[ \cdot \mid X = x]$ defined in your context?

Comment: @Sangchul Lee Seems I have used conditional notation in a wrong way. Edited.

Comment: In that case, the proof is quite simple: for each $\omega \in \Omega$, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(X(\omega)) = 0$$ by the assumption. So $\{\omega : \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(X(\omega)) = 0\} = \Omega$ and this event has full probability (i.e. probability 1).

Comment: @SangchulLee, Sorry but I totally misunderstood the story, so there was an extensive editing. In this case $x_n$ also varies and what I only seek is convergence in probability. Any help?

Comment: Would you be more specific about the quantifier $\forall x_n$? If $f_n(x_n) \to 0$ for *any* sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, then again, for each $\omega \in \Omega$ we have $f_n(X_n(\omega)) \to 0$.